# SAPUI5 get single property from JSON-Model

Tags: json, model, attributes, sapui5

I am currently trying to figure out how I can retrieve a single value from a  sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel

in my main view:

```
var gConfigModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

var getConfigCallback = function(config) {
    gConfigModel.setData(config);
};

oController.getConfiguration(getConfigCallback);
console.log(gConfigModel);
```

in my controller:

```
getConfiguration : function(callback) {

    var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxx/ConfigurationSet('Initialize')";

    var config = {};
    callback(config);

    $.getJSON(sServiceUrl).done(function(data) {
        config = data.d;
        callback(config);
    });
},
```

In my console.log statement I can see that the data was successfully passed from the backend and successfully set to the JSON model. My requirement is to store the value of attribute Editable in a single variable.

[image: console.log-statement]

I already tried gConfigModel.getProperty('/'), didnt work. tried to access gConfigModel.oData was undefined .. How can I store it in a single value?

**Solution Comment:** If you catch data from a backend, you have to take care how long it takes. data can be available later then expected, in my case I added 1s timeout, afterwards I can access the property easily

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     console.log(gConfigModel.getProperty('/Editable'));
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: getData() should return the object oData. So to access Editable just use var editable = gConfigModel.getData().Editable;

Comment: the getData() method returns an object, which has no nodes or attributes below .. :( What am I missing?

Comment: For anyone looking in on this case later, it was primarily due to the standard 'async-things-do-not-happen-in-assumed-sequence' issue. Read about `ajax success callbacks` for background. Essentially the OP tried to access data that was not yet returned from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<script>
    function getConfiguration(callback) {

        var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxx/ConfigurationSet('Initialize')";

        var config = {};

        var data = {
            "d": {
                "_metadata": "",
                "Backup01": "01",
                "Editable": "True"
            }
        };

        setTimeout((function() {
            config = data;
            callback(config);
        })(), 2000);
    };
    var gConfigModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    var getConfigCallback = function(config) {
        gConfigModel.setData(config);
        alert(gConfigModel.getProperty("/d/Editable"));
    };

    getConfiguration(getConfigCallback);
</script>
```

Comment: the thing is, I cannot access "var data" like you do because it is set during my callback function. it is set to my model during var getConfigCallback, but it seems this is not accessible later in my code... I dont get it..

Comment: hi zyrex, i simulate your callback using setTimeout, it is working.

Comment: does this mean I can only access my property during function(config)? my intent is to receive the json, and store this single value in a global variable to access it everywhere in my main view..

Comment: once again you gave me the right hint, the thing is Im fetching data from an sap backend and did not respect the time it may took. so code moved on, when I wait 5 seconds before e.g. getProperty, then its there!!! But I thought the callback function is exactly doing this for me, waiting for a function to be finished?? THANKS ALLEN, godlike. definitively.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't advise using the model's `getData()` method since it is deprecated.

A much better solution is to use `gConfigModel.getProperty("/Editable")`
(I'm using the root slash here since your property resides in the root of your model)

In the same way, you can also set your data: 
`gConfigModel.setProperty("/Editable", <your new value>)` instead

Comment: this was my first thought, but it does not work. currently I have another node below oData called "d", I try to access like you said gConfigModel.getProperty("/d/Editable") but it does not work, do I miss something? I also tried my old model without "d"-subnode, it also says undefined when I console.log the getProperty method... :(

Comment: thanks for access help! I missed respecting a time delay when transferring data from a backend!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thanks for the effort to find solutions of our Problems! (at least, those regarding It stuff.. :) )

I've found a solution which I think is a little bit more save because the timeout is maybe somewhat arbitrary - it would depend on the machine or the amount of data that is to be fetched?

Therefore, I am using an `attachRequestCompleted` function:

```
with sUrl_2="path-to-my-service";
var oModel_2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sUrl_2);

oModel_2.attachRequestCompleted(function(data) {

       //now, i can access the data stored in the oModel_2, either by getProperty, or by DOM: oModel_2.oData.d.Vendor

        gv_selLieferant = oModel_2.getProperty("/d/Vendor");
        gv_selEinkOrg = oModel_2.getProperty("/d/PurchOrg");
        gv_selEinKGru = oModel_2.getProperty("/d/PurGroup");

    });
```

Comment: this is the most correct answer. Using the `attachRequestCompleted` event. The only thing that can be add is that by using `this` pointer you can reach the Odata model.